# Graceful shutdown while processing messages from queue with Bunny gem

Tags: ruby, amqp

I'm using Bunny gem for consuming messages via AMQP. My app is subscribed for messages in a queue, it's a neverending blocking call (via subscribe block). I'd like it to shut down gracefully while the process is interrupted (e.g. ctrl+c in terminal). What's the proper way to do it? I would like it to process the current message if it's processing one and then jump out of the block.

code example:

```
trap("INT") do 
  puts "Stopping now"
  Indexer.client.stop # ???
end

module Indexer
  extend self

  def run    
    client.queue('indexer.index').subscribe do |msg|
      # omitted
    end
  end

  def client
    @client ||= Bunny.new.tap(&:start)
  end

end

Indexer.run # runs forever
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 2 years old, and you've probably figured out something by now.  That said, the way I'd handle this would be to put a 'should I quit?' check at the end of your subscribe loop, and then have your SIGINT trap toggle the variable.  Bunny itself is pretty good about cleaning up all the AMQP connection stuff, so you really would only need to worry about your own bits on exiting.